# When should I disable animations?

Tags: jquery

jQuery has this awesome simple way of disabling animations:

`jQuery.fx.off`

However, in practice, when should I use it? Should I detect browser capabilities using Modernizr to filter out which browsers it is best to disable animations for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major use cases for this:

**1. Performance related reasons:**
If users experience much lower performance than expected on a particular device that you are supposed to be supporting, then use this method. Make sure that you do this using feature detection mechanisms following a graceful degradation mentality. [More details on this issue](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/modernizr-the-html5-and-css3-feature-detection-library.html#fbid=PTLgD-I15om)

**2. Accessibility related reasons:**
If your target audience might contain people who suffer from a form of disability (this is changing and in more counties you are expected to support disable users regardless of your target population) then you need to include this as an accessibility feature option for your users. e.g. next to the increase font size button.